# LaTeX failed to compile

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I could not knit PDF on r markdown. The error message said that the LaTeX failed to compile. I  am using a mac computer. I updated LaTeX, r markdown, and r studio. Does anyone have any idea what happened?

Here is the error message,

```
"output file: Untitled.knit.md

! Emergency stop.
<*> Untitled.tex

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Untitled.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for             debugging tips. See Untitled.log for more info.
Execution halted "
```

Also, here is the log file message,

```
"This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 
2020.6.25)  25 JUN 2020 04:48
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Untitled.tex
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>)
! Emergency stop.
<*> Untitled.tex
             
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 16 strings out of 482394
 386 string characters out of 5945893
 234434 words of memory out of 5000000
 15910 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 12i,0n,15p,44b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"
```

Comment: Can you show the .tex file?

Comment: Hi, here is the link to the .tex file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14wU38jeh1TcMfo0NoeTaw4GJ8ZXNEZXA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded     format=pdflatex 2020.6.25)  25 JUN 2020 16:56
    entering extended mode
     restricted \write18 enabled.
     %&-line parsing enabled.
    **sys-test-2.tex
    (./sys-test-2.tex
    LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
    L3 programming layer <2020-06-18>)
    ! Emergency stop.    
    <*> sys-test-2.tex

Comment: Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
     16 strings out of 482419
     394 string characters out of 5944269
     234276 words of memory out of 5000000
     15897 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
     532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
     14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
     12i,0n,15p,46b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

    !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: The above messages are from my log file

Comment: Ah, the .tex file is empty, no surprise the compilation fails. So the problem is somewhere in the conversation from markdown to tex. Can you make a minimal example and show how you convert it?